# Docker compose update all images in all containers of all stacks, and restart all the influenced stacks

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

Can I use a simple command line or GUI, to update all the installed containers of all stacks, and restart all of them, instead of running

```sh
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
```

for each directory containing a docker-compose.yml file?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A quick way by scripting it.

```
$ find . -type f -name docker-compose.yaml -exec dirname {} \; |while read dir
do
  pushd "$dir"
  docker-compose down
  docker-compose pull
  docker-compose up -d
  popd
done
```

Comment: You forgot the `docker-compose pull` command between down and up, meaning the script you provided won't pull any updated images but only restart all stacks. The OP was specifically asking for a way to pull all stacks, though.

Comment: Note that `docker-compose.yaml` files can end in `.yml` instead. To account for that, I call the find command with `-name docker-compose.y*ml`